# How to test catch statement in async await Action

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

### Problem

I have an Action which awaits an API function. The happy path in the try is easily testable with my mocked API. However, unsure as to the best way to test and cover the `.catch`.

#### Actions

```
import {getRoles} from '../shared/services/api';

export const Actions = {
    SET_ROLES: 'SET_ROLES'
};

export const fetchRoles = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const response = await getRoles();
        const roles = response.data;

        dispatch({
            type: Actions.SET_ROLES,
            roles
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: Actions.SET_ROLES,
            roles: []
        });
    }
};
```

#### Actions Test

```
import {fetchRoles} from '../party-actions';
import rolesJson from '../../shared/services/__mocks__/roles.json';
jest.mock('../../shared/services/api');

describe('Roles Actions', () => {
    it('should set roles when getRoles() res returns', async () => {
        const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

        await fetchRoles()(mockDispatch);
        try {
            expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                type: 'SET_ROLES',
                roles: rolesJson
            });
        } catch (e) {
            // console.log('fetchRoles error: ', e)
        }
    });

    // Here is the problem test, how do we intentionally cause
    // getRoles() inside of fetchRoles() to throw an error?
    it('should return empty roles if error', async () => {
        const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

        await fetchRoles('throwError')(mockDispatch);

        expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            type: 'SET_ROLES',
            roles: []
        });
    });
});
```

#### Mocked API

```
import rolesJson from './roles.json';

export const getRoles = async test => {
    let mockGetRoles;

    if (test === 'throwError') {
        //   console.log('sad')
        mockGetRoles = () => {
            return Promise.reject({
                roles: []
            });
        };
    } else {
        // console.log('happy')
        mockGetRoles = () => {
            return Promise.resolve({
                roles: rolesJson
            });
        };
    }

    try {
        const roles = mockGetRoles();
        // console.log('api mocks roles', roles);
        return roles;
    } catch (err) {
        return 'the error';
    }
};
```

^ Above you can see what I tried, which did work, but it required me to change my code in a way that fit the test, but not the actual logic of the app.

For instance, for this test to pass, I have to pass in a variable through the real code (see `x`):

```
export const fetchRoles = (x) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const response = await getRoles(x);
        const roles = response.data;
```

How can we force `getRoles` in our mock to throw an error in our sad path, `.catch` test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the test and got the line coverage for the `.catch` by adding a function called `mockGetRolesError` in the mock api file:

Thanks to @skyboyer for the idea to have a method on the mocked file.

```
import {getRoles} from '../shared/services/api';

export const Actions = {
    SET_ROLES: 'SET_ROLES'
};

export const fetchRoles = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const response = await getRoles();
        const roles = response.data;
        // console.log('ACTION roles:', roles);

        dispatch({
            type: Actions.SET_ROLES,
            roles
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: Actions.SET_ROLES,
            roles: []
        });
    }
};
```

Now in the test for the sad path, I just have to call `mockGetRolesError` to set the internal state of the mocked api to be in a return error mode.

```
import {fetchRoles} from '../party-actions';
import rolesJson from '../../shared/services/__mocks__/roles.json';
import {mockGetRolesError} from '../../shared/services/api';
jest.mock('../../shared/services/api');

describe('Roles Actions', () => {
    it('should set roles when getRoles() res returns', async () => {
        const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

        try {
            await fetchRoles()(mockDispatch);
            expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                type: 'SET_ROLES',
                roles: rolesJson
            });
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    });

    it('should return empty roles if error', async () => {
        const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

        mockGetRolesError();
        await fetchRoles()(mockDispatch);

        expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            type: 'SET_ROLES',
            roles: []
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mock `getRoles` API on per-test basis instead:

```
// getRoles will be just jest.fn() stub
import {getRoles} from '../../shared/services/api'; 
import rolesJson from '../../shared/services/__mocks__/roles.json';

// without __mocks__/api.js it will mock each exported function as jest.fn();
jest.mock('../../shared/services/api'); 

it('sets something if loaded successfully', async ()=> {
  getRoles.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(rolesJson));
  dispatch(fetchRoles());
  await Promise.resolve(); // so mocked API Promise could resolve
  expect(someSelector(store)).toEqual(...);
});

it('sets something else on error', async () => {
  getRoles.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject(someErrorObject));
  dispatch(fetchRoles());
  await Promise.resolve();
  expect(someSelector(store)).toEqual(someErrornessState);
})
```

I also propose you concentrate on store state after a call not a list of actions dispatched. Why? Because actually we don't care what actions in what order has been dispatched while we get store with data expected, right?

But sure, you still could assert against `dispatch` calls. The main point: don't mock result returned in `__mocks__` automocks but do that on peer-basis.

Comment: My concern is this may be a good way to test the end redux state, but I'll be missing the line coverage for the `.catch`. Your `mockReturnValue` gave me the idea to add this in my mock file tho, and with that I'm able to test the sad path :D thoughts?

Comment: whatever works to you. testing actions also works but I found it be quite time-consuming and kind of less maintainable. but I'd be set value explicitly instead of using helper from mock - better readability, easier to update, extending with new response versions for free...